# Highlight the div onclick and unhighlight second time click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```js
var a = document.getElementById('a');
var b = document.getElementById('b');
b.style.cursor = 'pointer';
a.style.cursor = 'pointer';
a.onclick = function() {
  $("#a").css("background-color", "red");
};
b.onclick = function() {
  $("#b").css("background-color", "yellow");
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="a" id="a">
  Logesh Logesh Logesh Logesh Logesh Logesh Logesh Logesh Logesh Logesh Logesh Logesh Logesh
</div>
<br>
<div class="b" id="b">
  Logesh Logesh Logesh Logesh Logesh Logesh Logesh Logesh Logesh Logesh Logesh Logesh Logesh
</div>
<br>
<div class="b" id="b">
  Logesh Logesh Logesh Logesh Logesh Logesh Logesh Logesh Logesh Logesh Logesh Logesh Logesh
</div>
```

I want to add background-color css to the div i click and again clicking on the same dive it should remove the BG color.

Here i wrote the code as getting id statically. I may get many div in future so i need to get the div id dynamically. like something $this.id bla bla... please help me. Thank u..

Comment: Give all your `div` elements a `class` on which you want to add this highlighting option.

Comment: Which language are you using? as you said it will be dynamic and you may get many div, that means its in for loop. so which language will you use for that?

Comment: also which colers do you want? here you have shown 2 colours , red and yellow.

Comment: A sidenote: _IDs should have to be unique for each element in a single page_.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/bq1hewvs/3/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `toggleClass` to toggle between highlight  and unhighlight

```
$('div').click(function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('red');
});
```

```js
 $('div').click(function(){
      $(this).toggleClass('red');
    });
```

```css
.red {
  background:red;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="a" id="a">
  Logesh Logesh Logesh Logesh Logesh Logesh Logesh Logesh Logesh Logesh Logesh Logesh Logesh
</div>
<br>
<div class="b" id="b">
  Logesh Logesh Logesh Logesh Logesh Logesh Logesh Logesh Logesh Logesh Logesh Logesh Logesh
</div>
<br>
<div class="b" id="b">
  Logesh Logesh Logesh Logesh Logesh Logesh Logesh Logesh Logesh Logesh Logesh Logesh Logesh
</div>
```

or use a data attribute to store your colors:

```js
$('div').click(function(){
      $(this).css('background',$(this).attr('data-color'));
  $(this).toggleClass('default');
    });
```

```css
.default {
  background:#fff!important;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="default" id="a" data-color="red">
  Logesh Logesh Logesh Logesh Logesh Logesh Logesh Logesh Logesh Logesh Logesh Logesh Logesh
</div>
<br>
<div class="default" id="b" data-color="yellow">
  Logesh Logesh Logesh Logesh Logesh Logesh Logesh Logesh Logesh Logesh Logesh Logesh Logesh
</div>
<br>
<div class="default" id="b" data-color="blue">
  Logesh Logesh Logesh Logesh Logesh Logesh Logesh Logesh Logesh Logesh Logesh Logesh Logesh
</div>
```

Comment: the second method data-color is angular js?

Comment: Thank friend, this is what i need.

Answer (score 1):

Try with [toggleClass()](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_toggleclass.asp) And `b` is two times there so use with class and apply with [**.each()**](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/misc_each.asp) .It will apply the each class  of `b` .

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#a').click(function(){
$(this).toggleClass("red");
})

$('.b').each(function(){
  $(this).click(function(){
$(this).toggleClass("yellow");
})
  })
})
```

```css
div{
  
  cursor:pointer;
}
.red{
  background-color:red;
 }
.yellow{
  background-color:yellow;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="a" id="a">
  Logesh Logesh Logesh Logesh Logesh Logesh Logesh Logesh Logesh Logesh Logesh Logesh Logesh
</div>
<br>
<div class="b" id="b">
  Logesh Logesh Logesh Logesh Logesh Logesh Logesh Logesh Logesh Logesh Logesh Logesh Logesh
</div>
<br>
<div class="b" id="b">
  Logesh Logesh Logesh Logesh Logesh Logesh Logesh Logesh Logesh Logesh Logesh Logesh Logesh
</div>
```

Comment: thanks man, but every time u get id here. That will make the code bigger if i have more div.

Answer (score 0):

Added toggleClass on .red class

```
a.onclick = function() {
    $("#a").toggleClass("red");
};
```

And style

```
<style>
.red {
  background-color:red;
}
</style>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bq1hewvs/1/

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use pure javascript, you don't need library just add this only
and add css `.blue { background:#06C;}`

```
var a = document.getElementById('a');
var b = document.getElementById('b');
b.style.cursor = 'pointer';
a.style.cursor = 'pointer';
a.onclick = function() {
var myButtonClasses = document.getElementById("a").classList;
   if (myButtonClasses.contains("blue")) {
      myButtonClasses.remove("blue");
   }else {
      myButtonClasses.add("blue");
   }
};
b.onclick = function() {
  var myButtonClasses = document.getElementById("b").classList;
    if (myButtonClasses.contains("blue")) {
      myButtonClasses.remove("blue");
    }else {
      myButtonClasses.add("blue");
    }
};
```

Comment: thanks man, but every time u get id here. That will make the code bigger if i have more div.